# static outgoing IP on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running in a GKE cluster (1.15.12-gke.2)  some applications that need to connect to a third-party API. This third-party API has mandatory IP filtering. So in order to get API authorized, I need to declare what are the public IP that I'll use to connect to the API.
My problem is that public IPs of GKE nodes are not stable across upgrade and it would prevent the use of node autoscaling & after every time of nodes restart IP will change

Is there any way to have a stable outbound public IP on GKE?

Thanks
-Ashok Patidar

Comment: Hello, could you specify if you are a running a public or private `GKE` cluster? If you are running or you are able to run a private `GKE` cluster you could use Cloud NAT: [Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: Overview](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview). Also there is a tutorial for an example setup: [Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: GKE Example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example).

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, the solution to have a static outbound IP in `GKE` is to use `Cloud NAT`.

> **Disclaimer!**
>
> A `Cloud NAT` gateway can perform NAT for nodes and Pods in a **private** cluster, which is a type of VPC-native cluster.
>
> *[Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: Overview: NAT with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#NATwithGKE)*

You can read more about private `GKE` clusters by following official documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Private cluster concept](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept)*

There is also an official guide showing the process of creating a private `GKE` cluster and then connecting it with `Cloud NAT`:

- *[Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: GKE example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example)*

> When following above guide you can choose to use previously reserved static IP address or create a new one. **This will be the IP that `GKE` nodes and pods will be using when communicating with "outside"**.

---

I ran a test where I spawned private `GKE` cluster with 3 nodes. Created pods that each one of them was scheduled on a different node. Every pod sent a packet to a remote server. Listening on remote server showed that every pod that sent a message had the same source IP:

```
tcpdump: listening on ens4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:06:11.692832 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 54, id 46751, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    35.198.XXX.XXX.1027 > 10.168.0.2.9833: # NODE1 (POD1) TO SERVER
    10.168.0.2.9833 > 35.198.154.155.1027: # REPLY TO (POD1)
    35.198.XXX.XXX.2051 > 10.168.0.2.9833: # NODE2 (POD2) TO SERVER
    10.168.0.2.9833 > 35.198.154.155.2051: # REPLY TO (POD2)
    35.198.XXX.XXX.1538 > 10.168.0.2.9833: # NODE3 (POD3) TO SERVER
    10.168.0.2.9833 > 35.198.154.155.1538: # REPLY TO (POD3)
```